# Mysql with variables and count method

Tags: php, mysql

First I am sorry if I pushed it in the wrong place but I am a little confused as this is my first time?

I am trying to create a sql query that retrieve a count of the id and set it in a variable but I got a strange results.

here is my code.

```
SET @order_count = 0,@refund ='';
SELECT @order_count := count(id) , @order_count @refund := (SubQuery) as refunds, IF(@refund > 0,( @order_count - @refund ), @order_count ) AS sold, FROM wp_shop_orders AS o
```

**Here is a screenshot of what I got.**

[image]

**Also when I run the command through the php using mysqli it returns the second column with empty value.**

[image]

Thanks

Comment: That screenshot shows a SUM not a COUNT

Comment: Oh sorry but the problem happened with both sum and count methods.

Comment: Why are you trying to put them in MySQL variables in the first place? What's wrong with just selecting it and using the result in PHP ?

Comment: I am using a complicated sql query with multi subqueries and many conditions. What I shared here is just a small part in the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is addressed in the [MySQL manual section on User-Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html). In particular, here:

> As a general rule, other than in SET statements, you should never
>   assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same
>   statement. For example, to increment a variable, this is okay:
>
> `SET @a = @a + 1;`
>
> For other statements, such as SELECT, you might get
>   the results you expect, but this is not guaranteed. In the following
>   statement, you might think that MySQL will evaluate @a first and then
>   do an assignment second:
>
> `SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1, ...;`
>
> However, the order of evaluation for
>   expressions involving user variables is undefined.

In other words, despite setting the value of `@order_count` "first" in your SELECT statement, the variable is clearly returning its original value (an empty string) when selected as the second column.

The manual continues (emphasis mine):

> Another issue with assigning a value to a variable and reading the
>   value within the same non-SET statement is that **the default result type of a variable is based on its type at the start of the statement.**
>   The following example illustrates this:
>
> `mysql> SET @a='test'; mysql> SELECT @a,(@a:=20) FROM tbl_name;`
>
> For this SELECT statement, MySQL reports to the client that column one is
>   a string and converts all accesses of @a to strings, even though @a is
>   set to a number for the second row. After the SELECT statement
>   executes, @a is regarded as a number for the next statement.
>
> To avoid problems with this behavior, either do not assign a value to
>   and read the value of the same variable within a single statement, or
>   else set the variable to 0, 0.0, or '' to define its type before you
>   use it.

In other words, since you declare the variable by assigning it the empty string, operations on the variable will be interpreted using string values, hence mysqli reporting the first column as the *string* '125068543' instead of an integer.

Now, you haven't told us what else you're doing with this value, but from the scenario you've presented, you can eliminate the expected results by setting (and referencing) your variable only once, like so:

```
SELECT @order_count := count(id) FROM wp_shop_orders AS o
```

Comment: Thanks,
So what I understood that it may works for some time and may not work with other. 
OK,here is a sample for what I want to do

   SET @\order_count = 0,@\refund ='';
   SELECT @\order_count :=count(id) , @\order_count, @\refund := (SubQuery) as refund, IF(@refund > 0,( @\order_count - @\refund ), @\order_count ) AS sold, FROM wp_shop_orders AS o

Comment: I have added a \ before the variable name as the website prevent me to add the comment with @\name

Comment: Ok, I believe your main take-away should be this: *do not* assign values to variables and also select the variables in the same SELECT query, as the results are non-deterministic. To better answer your question, please edit the question to include your actual query; it's likely you should be joining on the subquery instead of trying to assign its result to a variable...

Comment: I have updated the question with the query.

About the subquery.

I can't use join because it duplicates the results and I have to handle this duplication via php and I have many records in database leads to a slowness and crash in sometimes.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, let me try that again. What you have in the question is only enough for us to answer "why doesn't selecting a variable in the same query where its value is assigned yield expected results?" To suggest what you could do instead, we really need to know *what data you have* and *what result you're trying to achieve*. A small example of data + query that reproduces the problem would improve your chances of getting a useful answer.

Comment: I already have it working with another solution, I was just trying to use it through the variables. but as I can see it will cause a problems :(

Any way Thanks very much for your immediate help.